# Domain forwarding with masking redirects to //redirect/

Tags: redirects, web-hosting

I have a problem with domain forwarding and I need to resolve it urgently!

- I have a website hosted with Epik.com with domain forwarding
- The website is https://tiagorangel.com and the forwarding should redirect to https://https--personal-website-tiagorangel2011.glitch.me/
- But it is redirecting to https://https--personal-website-tiagorangel2011.glitch.me//redirect/
- The problem is that https://https--personal-website-tiagorangel2011.glitch.me//redirect/ does not exist, so a "Not found" error is shown.

Help need! Below is a screenshot of the Epik panel.

[image: Epik.com panel]

Comment: A "masked redirect" or "frameset redirect" as they are are also called is almost never a desired solution. They have two big problems: search engines still index the target of the redirect and users that get the redirect have trouble using the site because the URL doesn't change as they navigate within the site. You should almost always set up your domain name to serve the content rather than redirect your domain name to it.

Comment: What hosting company are you using?

Comment: Epik.com, as I said in the question.

Comment: Do you own `glitch.me` too?

Comment: No, I do not! Glitch.com is external hosting

Comment: https://glitch.com/about

Comment: So your host is actually glitch, not epik.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using domain forwarding with masking, you just need to follow [the instructions from Glitch for adding your custom domain](https://glitch.happyfox.com/kb/article/9-how-do-i-add-a-custom-domain-to-my-glitch-project/):

> - Open the project in the editor.
> - Click Tools located on the lower-left side of the page.
> - Click Custom Domains.
> - Enter your custom domain URL (`www.example.com`) and then click Add Domain.
> - Now, go to your domain name registrar's website and create a CNAME entry, adding `glitch.edgeapp.net` as the target.

After setting up a custom domain using glitch you can remove your Epik hosting, you won't need it.